# DataTable angular fixed column

Tags: angularjs, datatable

I'm using **DataTable angular** plugin with the **FixedColumns** option but when i load the table i have an error and i don't know how to fix it !:

Error: this.s is undefined ._fnConstruct/..`/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js:13:452`

Here's my ng controller :

```
$scope.persons= [];
    $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
       .withOption('scrollY', '300px')
        .withOption('scrollX', '300px')
        .withOption('scrollCollapse', true)
        .withOption('paging', false)
         .withFixedColumns({
             leftColumns: 1
         })

        $resource('app/data.json').query().$promise.then(function (persons) {
        $scope.persons= persons;
    });
```

View :

```
<table id="showcase-fixedcolumns" datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-column-defs="dtColumnDefs" class="row-border hover">

<tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
...
</tr>
</table>
```

The datas are loaded and the scrolling works fine but the first column is not fixed

Comment: What if you npm install @types/datatables.net-fixedcolumns   ?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include the two plugin seed files after jquery, angular & datatables have loaded

```
<script src="{yourPath}/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.js"></script>
<script src="{yourPath}/angular-datatables.fixedcolumns.min.js"></script>
```

and the CSS if needed

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{yourPath}/css/dataTables.fixedColumns.css">
```

You'll have to include the plugin as a module as well

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['datatables', 'datatables.fixedcolumns']);
```

Comment: injecting ```'datables.fixedcolumns'``` is causing error